# Can't remove single quote from a string inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, single-quotes

I'm trying to output key value pairs from an object that has been stringified.  But as soon as a single quote is detected, the data stops the output.

This is what I am getting:

```
[{"name":"john
```

But would like to see:

```
[{"name":"john's world"}]
```

This is the javascript code:

```js
$(function() {

    var allObjects = [

        {
            name: "john's world",
            msg: "hello world"
        }, {
            name: "billy",
            msg: "goodbye"
        }
    ]

    apiResults(allObjects);

    function apiResults(processedItems) {

        var output = '';

        output += "<form class='add-item-form' method='get'>";
        output += "<label for='item-input'>Enter a name to save your list and press ENTER</label><br><br>";
        output += "<input type='text' id='item-input' name='item-input' title='Item' required autocomplete='off' placeholder='my wine list' autofocus>";
        output += "<input type='hidden' id='search-results-array'  name='search-results-array' value='" + JSON.stringify(processedItems) + "'>";
        output += "<button id='submitBtn' type='submit'>Add item</button>";
        output += "</form><br>";

        output += "<div class='container'>";
        $('#results').html(output);
        console.log(processedItems);
    }

    $(document).on('submit', '.add-item-form', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (event.type === 'keypress' && event.which === 13 || event.type === 'submit') {


            // searchArray is attached to the api result
            var searchArray = $('#search-results-array').val();
            console.log("searchArray", searchArray);

        }

    });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle of the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/marcusk1/mpahzfw4/15/

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Which problem are you trying to solve by removing the single quote? There is probably a better solution than using string replacement.

Comment: When I receive data from an api call, some of the text has apostrophe's.  This causes the 'Unexpected end of JSON input' error.  So I'm trying to remove the apostrophe so that the rest of the data can come through.

Comment: there is no single `'` in the string you've shown. it ends in a `*` ... is this the whole text string you are getting from places unknown? because that's definitely not JSON - and there's no reason you should be getting a JSON error given the code you've shown - perhaps you need to show some more context to your code

Comment: Single quotes do not usually cause such an error. Proof: `console.log(JSON.parse("{\"foo\": \"single'quote\"}"))`. Please provide more context.

Comment: The data that I initially receive from the api call is in an object under the key name: "Stag's Leap Wine Cellars KARIA Chardonnay 2014".

Comment: Are you certain it's a single-quote (ASCII decimal 39)?  Some analysis might be in order (try `String.charCodeAt`)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: I will try analyzing the single quote.  Thanks Kris.

Comment: @KrisKoskelin What other character would be likely to cause a problem?

Comment: Whatever your regexp is trying to do, it's not going to work as you expect. The replacement string literal `"\\$1"` is going to be interpreted as the string `\$1`, which will replace your single quotes with `\'`. That will modify an input such as `foo'bar` to `foo\'bar`, which when parsed by JSON.parse will turn into `foo'bar`, putting you exactly back where you started.

Comment: @torazaburo, thanks for providing all that info.  I'll keep digging into my code to see if it's something else.

Comment: I've updated my question to include an example of the problem I'm having as well as a link to jsfiddle.